# How would I go about merging two models together in-game to create a new model?

Tags: opengl, graphics-programming

Let's say I have two models: model 1 is hilt and model 2 is blade. How would I merge these to models together to create a sword?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"?

Comment: By merge I mean I want the two models to come together to make a new model.

Comment: seems like what Unity does when it prepares a "static batch". This is offline, or, at worst, at level loading stage. but real time is risky, on high end machines it could be fine, especially with measures to spread lengthy treatment over frames, or in threads. Usually this kind of problems are simply "solved" by using 2 draw calls.

Comment: You can always keep them separate and render them together.

Answer (score 1):

just append the data and adjust the indices:

if the hilt has X vertices and the blade has Y then you first put the X vertices of the hilt and then put the vertices of the blade. Do the same for the indices but add X to each index of the blade.

This will then force you to use only a single texture for the entire model.